# how to use css in jsp pages

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to use css file from my jsp pages but page does not see the css codes.

this is my .jsp file;

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sources/css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="/sources/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
```

[image]

[image]

this is my configuratin file

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("com.sprhib")
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class BaseTestConfig {

        @Bean
        public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
            UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
            resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
            return resolver;
        }


            public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/sources/**").addResourceLocations("/sources/");
        }

    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by page does not see the css codes?

Comment: Have you added the resource configuration in your dispatcher-servlet.xml file? Eg. <mvc:resources mapping="/sources/**" location="/sources/"/>

Comment: I dont add it because I dont use xml configuration I am using annotation configuration how can do this. My code is like that;

Answer (score 3):

The webapp is not deployed as the root webapp. So it has a "context path". The path to access the index.html file which is at the root of your webapp, for example, is in fact something like

```
http://localhost:8080/myfirstwebapp/index.html
```

This is what the location bar of your browser contains, and `/myfirstwebapp` is the context path of your application.

So, if you page contains `href="/sources/css/foundation.css"`, the browser will try to load the css file from

```
http://localhost:8080/sources/css/foundation.css
```

and not from

```
http://localhost:8080/myfirstwebapp/sources/css/foundation.css
```

You thus need to prepend the context path to **all** the absolute URLs in your webapp. Using the JSTL:

```
href="<c:url value='/sources/css/foundation.css'/>"
```

Without the JSTL:

```
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/sources/css/foundation.css"
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **/** in **/sources**. This will work

Comment: Only if he's accessing a URL at the root of the webapp.

Comment: Yes you're right. This will only work if @EmreAltun has his web app mapped to be ROOT

Comment: No. Even if the webapp is the root webapp, it will only work for URLs directly under the root 'i.e. it will work with /hello.jsp, but won't for /foo/bar/hello.jsp).

Answer (score 0):

Try to call those css directly through your web browser with full URL path.
It depends on what's your application path defined in your Tomcat or web server.

If it's mapped like http://yourdomain.com/ ( root ), it should be http://yourdomain.com/sources/css/foundation.css, but if it's mapped like http://yourdomain.com/test or something, URL for CSS should be http://yourdomain.com/test/sources/css/fundations.css.

You may use either relative pass for those, or introduce PATH variable so that link always created like http://yourdomain.com/PATH/sources/css/foundations.css in the source code.